# Using the Lorentz operators to build polynomials that converge to a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, approximation-theory

### Questions

Let $f(\lambda):[0,1]\to (0,1)$ have a $\beta-\lfloor\beta\rfloor$)-Hölder continuous $\lfloor\beta\rfloor$-th derivative, where $\beta>0$.

1. Find explicit bounds, with no hidden constants, on the approximation error for the "[**Lorentz operator**](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00365-010-9108-5)" $Q_{n,r}(f)$ (described below), and for the polynomials $(f_n)$ and $(g_n)$ formed with it. The bounds should have the form $C\cdot\max((\lambda(1-\lambda)/n)^{1/2}, 1/n)^\beta$, where $C$ is an explicitly given constant depending only on $f$ and $\beta$.
2. Find the hidden constants $\theta_\alpha$, $s$, and $D$ as well as those in Lemmas 15, 17 to 22, 24, and 25 in the "[New Coins from Old, Smoothly](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00365-010-9108-5)" paper.
3. Verify my proof of the order-2 Lorentz operator's error bounds in [**my Proposition B10A**](https://peteroupc.github.io/bernapprox.html#Results_Used_in_Approximations_by_Polynomials).

### New coins from old, smoothly

[Holtz et al. 2011](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s00365-010-9108-5.pdf), in the paper "New coins from old, smoothly", studied a family of polynomials $(Q_{n,r} f)$ (which they call the *Lorentz operators*) that approximate a continuous function $f$.

They used the Lorentz operators to build a family of polynomials $(g_n)$ that converge from below to $f$ and satisfy the following: $(g_{2n}−g_{n})$ is a polynomial with non-negative Bernstein coefficients, once it's rewritten to a polynomial in Bernstein form of degree exactly $2n$.

They proved, among other results, the following:

A function $f(\lambda):[0,1]\to(0,1)$ admits a family $(g_n)$ described above that converges at the rate—

- $O((\Delta_n(\lambda))^\beta)$ if and only if $f$ is $\lfloor\beta\rfloor$ times differentiable and has a ($\beta-\lfloor\beta\rfloor$)-Hölder continuous $\lfloor\beta\rfloor$-th derivative, where $\beta>0$ is a non-integer and $\Delta_n(\lambda) = \max((\lambda(1-\lambda)/n)^{1/2}, 1/n)$.  (Roughly speaking, the rate is $O((1/n)^{\beta})$ when $\lambda$ is close to 0 or 1, and $O((1/n)^{\beta/2})$ elsewhere.)
- $O((\Delta_n(\lambda))^{r+1})$ only if the $r$th derivative of $f$ is in the Zygmund class, where $r\ge 0$ is an integer.

The scheme is as follows:

Let $f$ be a continuous and $r$-times differentiable function—

- that maps [0, 1] to the open interval (0, 1), and
- whose $r$th derivative is $\beta$-Hölder continuous, where $\beta$ is in (0, 1).

Let $\alpha = r+\beta$, let $b = 2^s$, and let $s\gt 0$ be an integer. Let $Q_{n, r}f$ be a degree $n+r$ approximating polynomial called a *Lorentz operator* (see the paper for details on the Lorentz operator). Let $n_0$ be the smallest $n$ such that $Q_{n_0, r}f$ has coefficients within [0, 1]. Define the following for every integer $n \ge n_0$ divisible by $n_{0}b$:

- $f_{n_0} = Q_{n_0, r}f$.
- $f_{n} = f_{n/b} + Q_{n, r}(f-f_{n/b})$ for each integer $n > n_0$.
- $\phi(n, \alpha, \lambda) = \frac{\theta_{\alpha}}{n^{\alpha}}+(\frac{\lambda(1-\lambda)}{n})^{\alpha/2}$.

Let $B_{n}(F)$ be the degree-$n$ Bernstein polynomial of $F$.

Let $C(\lambda)$ be a polynomial as follows: Find the degree-$n$ Bernstein polynomial of $\phi(n, r+\beta, \lambda)$, then rewrite it as a degree-$n+r$ Bernstein polynomial.

Then the degree $n+r$ polynomial that approximates $f$ is— $$g(n, r,\lambda) = f_{n}(\lambda) - D \cdot C(\lambda)\tag{1}$$.

However, the Holtz method is not yet implementable, in part because it relies on hidden constants with no upper bounds given.

### Background

I asked this question in order to solve the so-called [*Bernoulli factory* problem](https://peteroupc.github.io/bernoulli.html), described next. We're given a coin that shows heads with an unknown probability, $\lambda$. The goal is to use that coin (and possibly also a fair coin) to build a "new" coin that shows heads with a probability that depends on $\lambda$, call it $f(\lambda)$. This is the *Bernoulli factory problem*, and it can be solved only if $f$ is continuous (Keane and O'Brien 1994).

However, since I asked this question I have found a [Bernoulli factory algorithm](https://peteroupc.github.io/bernsupp.html#Another_General_Algorithm) that I believe is general enough to cover all the cases that this question would help solve.

Since this question may be of broader interest, though, I leave this question open.  See also my [other open questions](https://peteroupc.github.io/bernreq.html) about the Bernoulli factory problem.

### My Attempt

The Python script [lorentz.py](https://github.com/peteroupc/peteroupc.github.io/blob/master/lorentz.py) shows my attempt to implement the Holtz approximation scheme. It implements an algorithm to toss heads with probability equal to a C2 or C4 continuous piecewise polynomial factory function.  However, it relies on an unproven conjecture (Conjecture 34) in the Holtz paper.

Based on this attempt, the C4 continuous case is efficient enough for my purposes, but the case of functions with lesser regularity is not so efficient (such as Lipschitz or C2).

### References

- Keane, M. S., and O'Brien, G. L., "A Bernoulli factory", ACM Transactions on Modeling and Computer Simulation 4(2), 1994.
- Holtz, O., Nazarov, F., Peres, Y., "New Coins from Old, Smoothly", Constructive Approximation 33 (2011).