# Explicit bounds on derivatives of moments related to Bernstein polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, approximation-theory

### Background

This question relates to finding explicit bounds for the derivatives of moments related to Bernstein polynomials.  Answering it will help me find explicit bounds for polynomials that approximate a continuous function in an appropriate sense; see:

- [Using the Holtz method to build polynomials that converge to a continuous function](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/407179/using-the-holtz-method-to-build-polynomials-that-converge-to-a-continuous-functi)

### Definitions

Define the following:

- $X$ is a binomial($n$, $p$) random variable.
- $p_{n,k}(x)={n \choose k} x^k(1-x)^{n-k}$ is a Bernstein basis function.
- $B_n(f)(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n f(k/n) p_{n,k}(x)$ is the Bernstein polynomial of $f$ of degree $n$.
- $\Delta_n(x) = \max(1/n,(x(1-x)/n)^{1/2})$.
- $T_{n,r}(x) = \mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}[X])^r] = \sum_{k=0}^n (k-nx)^r p_{n,k}(x)$ is the $r$-th central moment of the binomial distribution.

### Derivatives of Moments

Holtz et al. 2011, in the paper "[New coins from old, smoothly](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s00365-010-9108-5.pdf)", included the following two results as part of studying polynomials that approximate a continuous function:

**Lemma 17**: For every integer $l\ge 0$ and every $\beta\ge 0$—  $$\sum_{k=0}^n |k/n-x|^\beta |p_{n,k}^{(l)}(x)|\le C\cdot(\Delta_n(x))^{\beta-l},$$ where $0\le x\le 1$ and $C$ is a constant depending only on $\beta$ and $l$.  (See also [Gonska and Zhou 1991, Lemma 2](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002190459190004T)).

**Lemma 18**: For every integer $j\ge 0$, $l\le j$, and $n\ge 1$—  $$|T_{n,j}^{(l)}(x)|\le Cn^j(\Delta_n(x))^{j-l},$$ where $0\le x\le 1$ and $C$ is a constant depending only on $j$ and $l$.

Note that Lemma 18 is trivial when $j\le 1$.

In a possible variant of Lemma 17, $|k/n-x|^\beta$ is replaced with $(k/n-x)^\beta$ and the sum is wrapped in absolute value brackets.

However, the constants in each result are hidden with no upper bounds given, making them unimplementable.

### Question

The question is:

Are there results that give reasonable and explicit upper bounds on the constants $C$ in each of the lemmas given above?  I have not been able to find any published result on this matter so far.  Without loss of generality, I am most interested in results where $j\le 10$ or $\beta\le 10$, since only these cases are needed for practical purposes.